# Cannot see Reorder button in Magento

Tags: magento

So, here is my problem:
I have the Reorder facility enabled in the Magento backend (navigating to System > Configuration, clicking the Sales tab, and selecting Yes from the Allow Reorder drop-down).

But I still cannot see the Reorder button in the front-end after completing an order.

I thought that maybe some of the products in the order that I am trying to Reorder may be out of stock and that's why I don't see the Reorder button.
But that doesn't seem to be the case either because even if I enable backorder, the Reorder button does not show.

Did searches on Google trying to identify what scenarios can result in the Reorder button not showing but didn't find anything very useful.
Hence, seeking help here...can anyone please help identify the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Old post I realise, but if your customer hasn't created an account for their order, the "re-order" button will not appear. It only appears for registered customers who have created an account. Customer's who checkout as a guest cannot re-order. I'm in the middle of trying to develop a way for guest orders to have the re-order button present too. But proving harder than it should be to create a quick module/extension to override the core files! Will update with progress.

Comment: Let me guess... you've hacked it together in an embarrassing hodgepodge? any further info would be helpful, as this is something that's really important for accounting and inventory purposes.

Comment: ave you had any success? I need to do this for my store

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled the reorder functionality in the Magento backend:

`System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Reorder`

This option should be set to `enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_canReorder`.
So you cannot reorder if the order is in status 'Hold' or 'Payment review' or if you have products that don't exist anymore or out of stock. Since you eliminated this last condition, check the order status.

Comment: The order status is actually 'Complete'. Also, it seems that some users see the 'Reorder' button and others do not - why might this the case?

Comment: You can debug that method and see why it returns false to you. It should give you an idea about the conditions that should be met.

Comment: Check if products are in stock first is my advice before delving into code.